Iterating over .getFeatures()
I've selected some polygons and created bounding boxes for them, then generated buffers. Now, I need to export each buffer to a separate .gpkg file. However, this loop saves all buffers multiple times instead of saving one buffer to one file.
field = "FID"

for features in Bboxed_gminy.getFeatures():
    buffer_param['OUTPUT'] = f'{work_dir}\\buffer_{features[field]}.gpkg'
    processing.run("native:buffer", buffer_param)

I've also tried this:
for feature in selected_gminy.getFeatures():
    Bbox_param['INPUT'] = feature[field]
    Bboxed_gmina = processing.run("native:boundingboxes", Bbox_param)['OUTPUT']
    buffer_param['INPUT'] = Bboxed_gmina
    buffer_param['OUTPUT'] = f'{work_dir}\\buffer_{feature[field]}.gpkg'
    processing.run("native:buffer", buffer_param)

but this loop doesn't work.
Just in case, these are the parameters I've used for bounding boxes and buffers:
TM = "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"

Bbox_param = {'INPUT':'',
              'OUTPUT':TM}

buffer_param = {'INPUT':'',
                'DISTANCE':buffer,
                'END_CAP_STYLE':2,
                'OUTPUT':TM}


Use selected_gminy.selectedFeatureCount() to work only with selected features. Also, to debug what the processing.run really does, do something like result = processing.run("native:buffer", buffer_param) then print(result) to see what really happen. It will help to sort out the issue.
